# Проблема с мелким запросом на postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

В общем, пытаюсь выполнить следующий запрос:

```
INSERT INTO T_USERS (chatId , state)
VALUES  (348966155, 'faculty')
ON CONFLICT (chatId) DO UPDATE
SET state = 'faculty';
```

Но pgadmin выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
ОШИБКА:  ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "ON")
LINE 3: ON CONFLICT (chatId) DO UPDATE
        ^
********** Ошибка **********
ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "ON")
SQL-состояние: 42601
Символ: 69
```

Comment: вроде всё правильно... в голом psql работает же?

Comment: Кажись, версия субд старая(9.3). Сейчас обновлю и напишу

Comment: точно... этот синтаксис с 9.5 доступен... в более старых ЕМНИП приходилось изощряться по разному...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Была старая версия(9.3). После обновления всё работает